# Pass result of find command as another command's multiple options

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I have a CLI tool that can take an option with multiple values - The syntax is like this:

```
CLI -I path/to/file1 -I path/to/file2 ...
```

How can I pass the result of the `find` command to this CLI?

---

**For reference**

If it's positional multiple arguments:

```
CLI path/to/file1 path/to/file2 ...
```

I can do:

```
find "dir" -name "pattern" -exec CLI {} \+
```

Comment: [Similar question on SU](https://superuser.com/q/1722419/432690).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If switching to `zsh` is an option, then, it's easily done there with:

```
CLI **/pattern(P[-I])
```

Where the `P` glob qualifier is used to insert an argument as a `P`refix to every matching file.

With GNU `find` and GNU `xargs` and a shell such as zsh or bash with support for ksh-style process substitution, you can also do:

```
xargs -xr0 -n100 -a <(find . -name pattern -printf '-I\0%p\0') CLI
```

`100` being chosen here as an even number that is hoped to be small enough that the list of arguments will fit in a single invocation of `CLI`. Without it, `xargs` could split the list in between the `-I` and the following file `p`ath. If it still doesn't fit within that `-n 100` constraint, thanks to `-x`, `xargs` will exit instead of running `CLI` with fewer arguments.

If `CLI` accepts `-Ipath/to/file` in addition to `-I path/to/file`, you can also do:

```
find . -name pattern -exec bash -c '
  exec CLI "${@/#/-I}"' bash {} +
```

Note that though `-exec cmd {} +` is meant to work around the limit on size of arguments by calling `cmd` several times if necessary, since bash adds a `-I` to each argument, it could still run into that limit when it executes `cmd` itself.

However since the length of that `-I` prefix happens to be the same as that of the `./` prefix that is added to all file paths and that we don't need here, we might as well tell `bash` to replace that `./` with `-I` and avoid the problem altogether:

```
find . -name pattern -exec bash -c '
  exec CLI "${@/#.\//-I}"' bash {} +
```

(that assumes that `.` itself (the starting file) doesn't match the *pattern*).

The `zsh` approach above doesn't attempt to work around the `execve()` system call limit, and will either run `CLI` once or fail to run it altogether. The limit there can be worked around using the `zargs` autoloadable function.

If it's important that `CLI` be called only once with one `-I file` per file, on modern versions of Linux, raising the stack size limit (with `limit stacksize 100M` in zsh for instance to raise it from the default of 8MiB) will help as the `execve()` limit is proportional to the stack size limit there.

Comment: `xargs -r0 -n100 -a <(find . -name pattern -printf '-I\0%p\0')`
is this equivalent to
`find . -name pattern -printf '-I\0%p\0' | xargs -r0 -n100 CMD`

Comment: @hongweiy, no it's not equivalent. In `find ... | xargs cmd`, `cmd`'s stdin will be /dev/null (with GNU `find`; with some other `xargs` implementations, it could even be the pipe from `find`).

Comment: can `zargs` make sure it doesn't split the `-I` and filename args over two distinct invocations?

Comment: @ilkkachu, only by specifying an even number of arguments with `-l 100` for instance (note that the `-s` limit still applies on top of that like for `xargs`; fixed in zsh, guessed at runtime in GNU `xargs`).

Answer (score 5):

Create an array of the args for `CLI` from the `find` output, adding `-I` before each file name, then call `CLI` with those args:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

args=()
while IFS= read -r file; do
    args+=( -I "$file" )
done < <(find "dir" -name "pattern" -print)

CLI "${args[@]}"
```

If your file names can contain newlines (doesn't look like it from the example in your question) then add `-d ''` to the `read` arguments and use GNU `find` and change `-print` to `-print0`.

That above assumes the contents of `args[]` won't exceed ARG_MAX.

Answer (score 3):

As a first try,

```
find . -print | sed 's/^/-I /'| xargs  echo
```

would do. Warning: this has a number of issues with spaces and/or special characters in the filenames.